# Expected number of rolls when repeatedly rolling an $n$-sided die

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expectation, dice

Suppose I roll an $n$-sided die once. Now you repeatedly roll the die until you roll a number at least as large as I rolled. What is the expected number of rolls
you have to make?

I know the answer to this problem, but I'm curious about possible solutions people might post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you roll a $k$, then there are $n-k+1$ possible numbers out of $n$ that will be greater than or equal to $k$. This gives rise to a [geometric distribution,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and so the expected number of rolls required after rolling a $k$ is $\frac{n}{n-k+1}$. Averaging over all $k$, the expected number of rolls will be $$\mathbb{E}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n-k+1}=H_{n}$$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

Comment: Could you explain why the expected number of rolls required is n/n-k+1?

Comment: This is a fundamental result about geometric distributions.  If you have $k$ chance of success on a given roll, the expected number of rolls for success is $\frac 1k$

Comment: I understand that (as in E[x] = 1/p for a geometric distribution.) then what is the the sum for? i dont fully understand the answer :(.

why is the expected being multiplied by 1/n and then the summation??

Comment: The sum is to cover the range of first rolls.  If the die has seven sides and the first roll is $4$, the chance on each roll to at least match it is $\frac 47$ so the expected number of rolls is $\frac 74$.  There are seven possible first rolls and we sum over them.

Comment: oh i see. just a general question: the question asks for for the average roll we have to make. Do we NEED to do all possible k's?

Comment: Do it by hand for small $n$, say $n=6$.  The average is dominated by cases where $k=n$.  It is the difference between the arithmetic mean and the harmonic mean.